clickable link on grid and populate text on the right side of the page(grid1 - link) (grid2-text about clickable link)-CSS code
My container set as grid display with 2 grids 30% 1fr by columns. grid1 are clickable list and I want my grid2 display texts that describes the link being clicked. Can anyone help me to code this on html/css. Thanks.
Didn't try anything yet as I am just new in this and trying to self study.
